# Set bitmap as wallpaper

Tags: android, bitmap, wallpaper

Well my bitmap have the exact size of the device screen, so for this example lets say 1200x780. If I set that bitmap as the wallpaper with this code:

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
```

My wallpaper gets zoomed and the image look horrible. So my question is:

If the bitmap is the exact same size as the device screen, how could I set it as wallpaper without it get zoomed?

Comment: in which devices are you facing this problem?

Comment: @user1283633 I have tested in Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, Nexus 7, S3 and S4. They all do the same thing.